# Como adicionar esse header ao SOAP?

Tags: php, soap

Olá,

Eu tenho que fazer uma verificação em um Web Service onde é enviado um CPF válido e me retorna um true ou false de acordo com a validação.

Eu consigo fazer acesso ao Web Service com o seguinte código:

```
    // INICIANDO O OBJETO CLIENTE INFORMANDO O WSDL 
    $client = new SoapClient('https://www5.oab.org.br/Integracao/CNA.svc?wsdl', $options = array(
                                                                                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
                                                                                'trace'=>1, 
                                                                                'exceptions'=> 0
                ));

    // NOME DA FUNÇÃO A SER EXECUTADA
    $function = 'AdvogadoRegular';

    // PARÂMETROS DA FUNÇÃO A SER EXECUTADA
    $arguments= array('AdvogadoRegular' => array( 'cpf'  => '99999999999' ));

    // URL DO WEB SERVICE
    $options = array('location' => 'https://www5.oab.org.br/Integracao/CNA.svc');
    echo 'Resposta: <pre>';
    print_r($result);   
    echo '</pre>';
```

Porém para ter acesso ao Web Service é necessário uma autenticação do tipo Soap Header Authentication. Abaixo segue o exemplo do Envelope SOAP.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:int="https://www5.oab.org.br/integracao/">
        <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
          <token xmlns="http://CFOAB.Integracao">CHAVE_DE_AUTENTICAÇÃO</token>
          <wsa:To>https://www5.oab.org.br/Integracao/CNA.svc</wsa:To>
        </soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Então eu tento adicionar o Header ao meu SOAP com o seguinte código.

```
// ADICIONANDO O HEADER
$auth = array('token' => 'xxxxxxxx');
$header = new SoapHeader('http://CFOAB.Integracao','token',$auth,false);

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Agora a minha dúvida é a seguinte, como se enviar os parâmetros corretamente ao header enviando também os parâmetros xmlns:wsa e wsa:To descrito no envelope SOAP?

Me ajudem nessa. Obrigado